# Java TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT") not working

Tags: java, timezone

It returns the default timezone for GMT.

Using the SimpleTimeFormat with "z" for timezone, it prints "PDT". But "PDT" is not in the list returned from TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().  Really strange!

Anyone knows why "PDT" is not a standard tz?  How to deal with this?  Someone invokes my API passing in "PDT" as the timezone.  Thanks.

Comment: time zone id != time zone name, two different concepts, id is for technical identification, names for (localized) display purposes

Answer (score 10):

## `PDT` is not a time zone

> Anyone knows why "PDT" is not a standard tz?

Because “PDT” is not a time zone!

The “PDT” is a pseudo-time zone used by the media to indicate vaguely a set of time zones plus an indicator if they intended during the period when [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is engaged or not (`PST`). Avoid these 2-4 letter codes as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

## Proper time zone names

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

By `PDT` any of these time zones, and more, may be intended:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Tijuana" ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Whitehorse" ) ;
```

But `PDT` might not mean this zone as Arizona does not participate in the Daylight Saving Time (DST) nonsense, and the `D` in the middle means DST.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Phoenix" ) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid `SimpleTimeFormat` class as it is a part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead.

Avoid `TimeZone` as well. Replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

## Pass `ZoneId`, not string

> Someone invokes my API passing in "PDT" as the timezone.

Change your API to take a `ZoneId` as an argument, rather than a mere String. That ensures valid values and gives you [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 4):

"PDT" is an abbreviation for Pacific Daylight Time.   It is used in conjunction with Pacific Standard Time to make up the Pacific time zone.

The time zone identifier for the Pacific time zone is `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  You should use that instead.

Read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and [Wikipedia's article on the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Comment: You will still often see `US/Pacific` and `US/Pacific-New` although they are now aliases to `America/Los_Angeles`.